# Can abstract types be used as the return type of a pure virtual function?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, pure-virtual, trailing-return-type

If I understand correctly, abstract types cannot be used as the return type of a pure virtual function. However, if a trailing return type is used, then gcc (but not clang) accepts the following code:

```
struct S {
    virtual auto f() -> S = 0; 
};
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rzj7Y3).

Is this a gcc bug, or does the language not require a diagnostic to be issued for this code?

Comment: Whehter this is ill-formed or not, there is no way to override that function.

Comment: @eerorika why is that? If `f` returned a `S*` then it would be overridable, yes?

Comment: @cigien Yes. The problem is with returning an `S` *by value*. Since `S` is abstract, the return value could not be instantiated.  Returning an `S` by pointer or reference is fine.

Comment: Aah, so the problem is the return type. I get that, this code is *wrong*. So the question remains, is the compiler obliged to diagnose this, or should I have to know better?

Comment: @cigien [gcc DOES NOT accept the code](https://ideone.com/HdQXAV), it does generate diagnostics, at least on derived types that try to override `f()`, anyway: "error: invalid abstract return type for member function ... because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘S’" ... "error: invalid abstract return type"

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are compiling a different program than the one in the question. See the godbolt link for the compiling example.

Comment: note that while gcc fails in your example, _**clang fails in the following one**_ (for which gcc comes up with proper diagnostics): [https://godbolt.org/z/xbsf34](https://godbolt.org/z/xbsf34)

Comment: @AmirKirsh Very interesting, that looks like a clang bug then. But the code is also wrong because the return type of `S` in the override is not *covariant* with `int`. I guess the question is, does *that* require a diagnostic?

Comment: @cigien there is no inheritance there, no need for covariant return type

Comment: @AmirKirsh Oh, you're right, seems to just be a clang bug then, same reasoning as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to C++17 [class.abstract]/3, an abstract type cannot be used as the return type of any function:

> An abstract class shall not be used as a parameter type, as a function return type, or as the type of an explicit conversion. Pointers and references to an abstract class can be declared. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> shape x;           // error: object of abstract class
> shape* p;          // OK
> shape f();         // error
> void g(shape);     // error
> shape& h(shape&);  // OK
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

There doesn't seem to be any special exception for pure virtual functions. Therefore, it seems that the answer is that the compiler is required to issue a diagnostic for your code.

Comment: Just to clarify, the "shall not..." means that a diagnostic should be issued?

Comment: @cigien Yes. See [intro.compliance]/1: "The set of *diagnosable rules* consists of all syntactic and semantic rules in this document except for those rules containing an explicit notation that “no diagnostic is required” or which are described as resulting in
“undefined behavior”."